# Making an Extra Copy and Paste Script

Tags: shell-script, x11, clipboard

How can I make a script which duplicates Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V (aside from the actual keybinding part, which I know already I can use xbindkeys for)?

So, for example, how could I make bash functions which copy the currently selected text to a new variable which is stored to be pasted with another script?

Answer (score 2):

You can alias xclip to behave like pbcopy/pbpaste on OS X.

```
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
```

And then fill and retrieve with e.g. `| pbcopy` and `pbpaste >`. Although if you're using a keybinding to do the copying part I guess you'll only need the latter.

If you're using it on a remote server you need X11 forwarding turned on on both client and server via `ForwardX11 yes` in .ssh/config and `X11Forwarding yes` in sshd_config.

Answer (score 0):

With a configurable window manager like dwm, openbox or many others, you can run this snippet `xclip -selection clipboard` while pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy and a similar script in the editor (vim, emacs, etc.) can retrieve the selection and insert it at point.